# how to use action names in rails3 routing with match

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a path of 
http://localhost:3000/recipes/1/ingredient/3

In my routes, I define

```
match  "/recipes/:recipe_id/ingredients/:id" => "ingredients#show"
```

However, I don't think I should be defining each action in my routes file, I shouldn't have a seperate entry for 'ingredients#show' than another for 'ingredients#edit'.

How do I define my match so that it takes either a default or uses the action defined in the link_to.

Currently, my link_to is defined as

```
<%= link_to 'Edit Ingredient', [@ingredient.recipe, @ingredient],
                                  :method => :edit,
                                  :controller => :ingredients %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to 'Edit Ingredient', [@ingredient.recipe, @ingredient],
                                  :method => :show,
                                  :controller => :ingredients %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would think you are looking for resources instead of match...

```
resources :recipes do
  resources :ingredients
end
```

gives you:

```
recipe_ingredients GET    /recipes/:recipe_id/ingredients(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"ingredients"}
    recipe_ingredients ingredient   /recipes/:recipe_id/ingredients(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"ingredients"}
 new_recipe_ingredient GET    /recipes/:recipe_id/ingredients/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"ingredients"}
edit_recipe_ingredient GET    /recipes/:recipe_id/ingredients/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"ingredients"}
     recipe_ingredient GET    /recipes/:recipe_id/ingredients/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"ingredients"}
     recipe_ingredient PUT    /recipes/:recipe_id/ingredients/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"ingredients"}
     recipe_ingredient DELETE /recipes/:recipe_id/ingredients/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"ingredients"}
         recipes GET    /recipes(.:format)                           {:action=>"index", :controller=>"recipes"}
         recipes ingredient   /recipes(.:format)                           {:action=>"create", :controller=>"recipes"}
      new_recipe GET    /recipes/new(.:format)                       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"recipes"}
     edit_recipe GET    /recipes/:id/edit(.:format)                  {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"recipes"}
          recipe GET    /recipes/:id(.:format)                       {:action=>"show", :controller=>"recipes"}
          recipe PUT    /recipes/:id(.:format)                       {:action=>"update", :controller=>"recipes"}
          recipe DELETE /recipes/:id(.:format)                       {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"recipes"}
```

so your edit action becomes:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit Ingredient', edit_recipe_ingredient_path(@ingredient.recipe, @ingredient) %>
```

and show action becomes:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit Ingredient', [@ingredient.recipe, @ingredient] %>
```

Otherwise, you will have to do something like:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit Ingredient', :controller => :ingredients, :action => :show, :id => @ingredient.id, :recipe_id => @ingredient.recipe %>
```

Comment: Thanks jenjenut. Strangely I always had the resources entry, but I had been writing my link_to incorrectly. If you hadn't been so thorough in your answer, it may have only lead me deeper down the rabbit whole!